How to fix USB with "device descriptor failed" issue in Windows 10
I use a Kingston DT50 USB to flash OS in different computers.
When I tried to format it from Windows 10, it failed. From then onwards, it is not usable as a flash drive and in Windows 10 device manager, it is showing pendrive as USB DEVICE DESCRIPTOR FAILED and also ERROR CODE 43. In properties, the USB is not ready.

This can happen when the contents of the USB get corrupted. If you have access to a Linux machine, you could try using the dd command to write the entire disk, or at least the start of it, full of 0 bytes so that Windows is forced to generate a new disk descriptor. Another option is Darik's Boot And Nuke to do the same - but careful about which disk you're nuking, it will quite happily zero your system.
